# RabbitMQ on Kubernetes kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local tls qlert

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I am about to install RabbitMQ image 3.7.17-debian-9-r37 on a Kubernetes cluster 1.15 using Helm charts.
While starting the RabbitMQ container I see the following error:

```
Failed to get nodes from k8s - 
{failed_connect, [{to_address, {"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},{inet,[inet],{tls_alert,{internal_error, "received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Internal Error - {unexpected_error...
```

It looks like something is wrong with TLS, but I am not sure what exactly.
Can anybody help understand the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. Would you please provide full error log? The most important part is truncated.

Comment: Hi, I am seeing the follwing error: "SSL Warning: Ignoring a CA certificate as it could not be correctly decoded. TLS client: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:334 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Internal Error ..."

Comment: However, the CA certificate is present in a folder that I indicate in configuration variable ssl-opttions.cacertfile in my values.yaml file. The CA cert is self-signed. Could this be the issue? Also, how can I disable the verification of the certificate at RabbitMQ side?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some research and found [this bug](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-968) which is what you are currently experiencing.

Current fix versions are:

> Fix Version/s:
>   21.3.8.5, 22.0.4

You can find Debian packages with fixed versions available [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#erlang-repositories).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi OhHiMark, Thank you for the indication. Actually, I am using a RabbitMQ image that is based on version 3.7.18 of RabbitMQ and 22.1 version of Erlang.

Comment: Do you know which RabbitMQ image would contain the fix? Thanks

Comment: Try the most recent one.